# Arduino ESP32 EEPROM commit() error in write

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32, eeprom

I want to save some values in memory and then be able to read them after turning off the esp.
I wrote the code based on the page https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-flash-memory/. The code worked, so I decided to check what maximum memory size I can enter before errors occur.

like

```
EEPROM.begin(12345678);
EEPROM.write(12345644,0xff);
EEPROM.commit();
```

When I went back to smaller values that should work I got error:

[538][E][EEPROM.cpp:196] commit(): error in write

code that should work:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

#define EEPROM_SIZE 10


void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();


  //read first 10 bytes
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("read first 10 bytes");
  Serial.println();
  EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);
  for(int i =0 ;i<EEPROM_SIZE;i++)
  {
    int state = EEPROM.read(i);
    Serial.print("addres: ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" value: ");
    Serial.println(state);

  }
  EEPROM.end();

  //write first 10 bytes
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("write first 10 bytes");
  EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);
  for(int i =0 ;i<EEPROM_SIZE;i++)
  {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" ");
    EEPROM.write(i,0xff);
    EEPROM.commit();

  }
  EEPROM.end();

  
  //read addres 2
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("read addres 2");
  EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);
    int state = EEPROM.read(2);
    Serial.print("value: ");
    Serial.println(state);
  EEPROM.end();
  
  // Wait 10 seconds
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Restarting in 10 seconds...");
  delay(10000);
  
  // Restart ESP
  ESP.restart();
}

void loop() {
  
  
}
```

the results of running the code on the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PwU6.png)

I was also using the Preferences library, but there was an error on saving here as well.

Is the error due to my attempts?

What should I do to make the code work?